# Check how many Values are equal in 2 list

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

i want to check, how many elements are equal in 2 list.

Equals means = the same value at the same position

I compare 2 list with the same length and there are only 1.0 or 0.0. I want to count only the 1.0.

My porblem is, im getting not the right values. 
 for example:

```
import numpy as np
a=[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0]
b=[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0]

x=np.array(a)
y=np.array(b)

c=np.sum(a==b)

c2=np.sum(x==b)

print c,c2

#c=0 and c2= 113
```

Thats actually not true, it is 7. np.count_nonzero() also didnt worked.

right now I'm doing it like this:

```
c=0
for i in range(len(x)):
    if x[i]==1.0 and y[i] ==1.0:
        c+=1
```

but this is obvioulsy extreme slow, because I have a big data set.

but with:

```
v=np.array([1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0])
w=np.array([1.0,0.0,1.0,1.0])

print np.sum(v==w)
# result is 3
```

it works?

Comment: You could use `zip`, which is more of a Python construct than a numpy one.

Comment: Why do you have a vector of floats that are only `1.0` or `0.0`. Why not use `bool`s?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do -

```
((x == y) & (x==1.0)).sum()
```

As mentioned in the question that the input arrays hold only `0` and `1.0`,so you could also do -

```
((x + y)==2.0).sum()
```

Please be careful when comparing against a floating point value. So, to be safe a `tolerance` value could be introduced.

Comment: I'd think `(x == 1.0) & (y == 1.0)` would be faster.

Comment: Could someone explain why bitwise "and" operator?

Comment: @cricket_007 Because you want to make sure both the values are `1.0` in the input arrays as mentioned in the question.

Comment: @cricket_007 `True & True == True`, `False & _ == False`, `_ & False == False`.

Comment: I know boolean logic, just not the implementation of bitwise operations between them in python. Is it a short-circuit difference?

Comment: @Veedrac Just tested and looks like your commented solution is really fast! Consider posting that as a solution! :)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind rounding errors in excessively huge arrays, then `(v * w).sum()` would be the most obvious answer. If you'd use arrays of `bool` as Veedrac commented, then there wouldn't be rounding errors either.

Comment: And faster with `.dot()` I think : `x.dot(y)`.

Answer (score 1):

A vanilla Python solution is to use `zip` and `sum`. Here I'll assume a boolean array, which is more appropriate, I think.

```
sum = 0
for (i,j) in zip(v,w):
    if i and j:
        sum += 1
```

Or in a more compact comprehension:

```
sum(i and j for (i,j) in zip(v,w))
```

Here's an example:

```
v = np.array([True, True, True])
w = np.array([True, False, True])
sum(i and j for (i,j) in zip(v,w))
# 2
```

This can be generalized if your data can't change to `sum(i == j == 1.0 for (i,j) in zip(v,w))`.

Comment: For the record, `i and j` is only equivalent to `i == j == True` for boolean values. It just checks truth values, not strict equality

Comment: @cricket_007 Yes, indeed.